# How to generate this teradata table?

Tags: html-table, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I would like to create a `Teradata` table with a table structure that looks like below.

`12-29-2008` will be start date. Basically I'd like to assign this as the start date with week number corresponding to this as `209`. Everything else afterwards should follow automatically i.e. calculated.

```
Column 1/Weekstart/Monday     Week num
12/28/2008                    209
1/5/2009                      210
...
12/27/2021                    887
```

I tried below but it could only create one row.

Please see image attached for an idea of what I want as the final dataset. 
[Table structure image is below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73d6S.png)

```sql
SEL 
  WeekBegin
, (WeekBegin - DATE '2008-12-29') / 7 + 209 as week_num
FROM Sys_Calendar.BusinessCalendar 
WHERE calendar_date = DATE '2008-12-29'
;
```

Thanks for your help!

Edit: After doing below-

```
SEL WeekBegin
, (WeekBegin - DATE '2008-12-29')/7 + 209 as week_num
FROM Sys_Calendar.BusinessCalendar 
WHERE 
  calendar_date >= DATE '2008-12-29' 
  and calendar_date <= DATE '2021-12-27';
```

My result looks like this:
[ResultsImage1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuBaD.png)
[ResultsImage2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deBs6.png)

It is not displaying the Monday of the week. Instead I see Sunday at the end of the table. Also the weeknum is 886, instead it should be 887.

Comment: You only get one row because your `WHERE` clause is restricting the result set to only return a single row.  Try changing it to something like `WHERE calendar_date >= DATE '2008-12-29`

Comment: There's already a week_number in sys_calendar.calendar and there's a day_of_week column  @ravioli Two user with the same question, seems to be some homework :-)

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that too :)  If it is homework, that's pretty cool that students are using Teradata!

Comment: @ravioli I tried below- SEL WeekBegin, (WeekBegin - DATE '2008-12-29')/7 + 209 as week_num
FROM Sys_Calendar.BusinessCalendar 
    WHERE 
  calendar_date >= DATE '2008-12-29' 
  and calendar_date <= DATE '2021-12-27';
It gives 3 rows and 3 weeknum for same date.
The errors are below
1. See duplicate entires (3 rows or 2 rows instead of 1)
2. Need to display monday of the week (however the last row displayed was 12/26/21 instead of 12/27/21 -- and the 
corresponding week num should be 887 and not 886. Any suggestion on how we can fix this to get Monday of every week
until 12/27/21?

Comment: BusinessCalendar's `WeekBegin` is related to the session calendar, in your case it's `Teradata` which means weeks start on Sunday. Instead of changing the session calendar you better switch to `sys_calendar.calendar` where Monday is indicated by `day_of_week = 2`. And use `calendar_date` instead of `weekBegin`